# Mastercard Nuget Xamarin implementation

Tags: xamarin, payment, mastercard

I want to use a Mastercard Payment Gateway service in my app but I'm uncertain which Nuget to use or how to implement them.

Currently I have the following nugets installed:

- MasterCard-Core
- Com.Mastercard.SDK
- Com.Mastercard.Masterpass.Merchant
- Com.Mastercard.Merchant.Checkout

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask but it would be helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://developer.mastercard.com/

Comment: https://github.com/jimbobbennett/awesome-xamarin#payments

Comment: were any of the nugets I installed any good? I can't find documentation on them

Comment: the mastercard api documentation only shows how to do it natively. How do i install on xamarin.forms? There is no gradle.properties file for me to edit.